# How to use different fonts (more than one) of react-native-vector-icons in one file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, icons, vector-icons

How to use 2 or more fonts (for example, FontAwesome and Entypo) of the react-native-vector-icons in one file?

Answer (score 10):

react-native-vector-icons exports a default `<Icon />` component. You can name your default imports anything you want. For your example you can do:

```
import FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import EntypoIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo'
```

This way you can use as many fonts as you want

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of this** (working for 1 font per file):

Importing:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

Using:

```
<Icon name="search" size={20} />
```

**Do this** (for 2 or more fonts per file):

Importing:

```
import { FontAwesome, Entypo } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
```

Using:

```
<FontAwesome name="search" size={20} />
<Entypo name="add-user" size={20} />
```

Comment: This won't work as the library doesn't export the fonts that way.

Comment: Here's the exact link from the creator himself https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/111#issuecomment-183906528

Comment: and yet it works. Sorry, not going to respond anymore, since I find this chat meaningless. If it does not work in your project - don't use. It works in mine - I will be sticking with it as long as it does. Cheers!

Comment: @KyleRoach The library absolutely does export this way. Test it and you will see. It does both default exports if you specify  'react-native-vector-icons' together with the family name, like you did in your answer, and it does named exports if you just specify 'react-native-vector-icons'.  So this answer is perfectly legitimate and does not deserve a downvote. +1

Comment: Doesn't work for me